# Counter-example Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

If we're given an arbitrary principal ideal domain $R$ and some $R$-module, call it $M$, is there an example of an $M$ that is not injective while $M_x$ is an injective module $\forall x \in max(R)$? Further is there an example of an injective M, while $M_x$ is not an injective module?

Or do we always have that one implies the other?

Comment: Are you saying $M_x$ is injective as an $R$ module or injective as an $R_x$ module?

Comment: As an $R$-module.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if we have a double implication for injective $M$ and injective $M_x$ (both as $R$-modules.